# name of object compiled by current translation unit in C

Tags: c

is there a macro or a global variable which through which I can learn about the name of the object file the current translation unit will be used for in C? I am only aware of the source file macro.

Thanks.

Comment: That would be kind of difficult for compilers with precompiled headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in standard C.

The preprocessor may be implemented as a separate program that has no knowledge of object files, so it can't be a built-in macro.

A compiler could in theory produce a symbol with the object file name, but that would be invalidated as soon as the object file is renamed by the user.

You can get the build system to `#define` the object name:

```
# Compile ${module}.c to ${module}.o
cc ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} -DOBJNAME=${module}.o -c -o ${module.o} ${module}.c
```

but the point about renaming still stands.

(This is just a snippet of shell code, but it could be turned into a `Makefile` rule, I suppose.)

Comment: I think your third paragraph is the most important point. The only way you could really get this information would be from the *linker*. If you have debugging turned on, it might remain embedded in the executable too, but you'd have to go to your platform's debugging API (or reverse-engineer it yourself) to get the info out. It wouldn't be trivial.

Comment: Your objection on renamed object files is substantial. Well, I want to produce different object files out of one source file (with different compilation options), link different version of object files accordingly to different versions of my program, and let during run time identify each component that has been linked (to make protocol output more readable).

Comment: @user411768: Do it in the build system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this exists. The only thing I can come up with is you could use the ## glue macro to combine `__FILE__` with ".o"... But even that isn't exactly what your asking for as you'd get foo.c.o.